# When did Patrick Stewart appear in Star Trek with hair?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I just saw this on [imgur](http://m.imgur.com/gallery/jZUuV), and while at first I didn't notice, image four shows Patrick Stewart in a Star Trek uniform ***with hair***.

[image: Patrick Stewart through the ages]

When did that happen?

Comment: See the BBC production of *Taming of the Shrew* from the 70s for a big curly mop on that jolly Scotsman. Or *Dune* for the "bald/mullet".

Answer (score 28):

It happened in Season 5 Episode 12 *Violations*

[image: Patrick Stuart with hair]

> In this episode, a member of an alien delegation traveling on the USS Enterprise molests members of the crew using telepathy.

<sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violations_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))</sub>

The hair appears in a [flashback](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Violations_(episode)#Background_information) according to Memory Alpha.

Comment: Your answer seems perfectly correct. I only would like to add, that if I'm not mistaken, then photo shown by you in the question (second to the right) does not actually comes from any ST episode, but from an initial cast-shootings. It would then lead us to a conclusion, that above presented (in answer) picture may present Patrick Stewart with fake hairs. If I'm not mistaken...

Comment: BOTH pictures present him with fake hair. Initially, the producers didn't want a bald captain, so they issued Patrick Stewart a toupee. I don't know when, why and how this idea changed.

Comment: @ray ate you sure about that?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - it (wanting Stewart to wear a toupee) was portrayed in the documentary Chaos on the Bridge.

Comment: @Ray Assuming that's correct, it's amazing how initially wrong the producers were.  It's good that they (or others) recognized their poor judgement and were willing to correct it.

Comment: If anybody is interested, a follow-up to the fake-hair-audition point [was asked here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120696/did-patrick-stewart-wear-a-toupee-for-his-the-next-generation-audition).